# Wordpress force the_content() to return complete when using WooCommerce Memberships

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-memberships

I'm using the WooCommerce Memberships plugin to restrict post access on my site, and this appears to limit `the_content()` to only show the first 55 words (`the_excerpt()`). Any content following that is hidden by the Membership plugin, which is the expected behaviour.

However, I am looking for a way to bypass this restriction programatically and force the_content(), or another function, to always return the full post content.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried get_the_content() function, if plugin applied restrictions on the_content() this should work.

```
 <?php get_the_content();?>
```

Comment: Yes, it returns the same shortened version of the_content() unfortunately.

Comment: Check Global object $post what it shows i am sure $post->post_content will show complete content.

Comment: Unfortunately the same is true, $post->post_content returns the same shortened version.